# Getting BoundField Value in gridview row_command

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I need to get the bound field value of the selected column in gridview_rowcommand.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

it will be like...

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
row.Cells[0].Text
```

Comment: Hey guys there is a way ., Actually I had alink button in the gridview and I have set the CommandArgument='<%# Eval("BoundfieldId") %#>'

And in the row command I have done ., 

Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); and i get the boundfield value of the selected row.

Comment: so what's the issue on above solution ?

Answer (score 5):

It should be something like this.

```
if (e.CommandName=="CommandName")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
        string boundFieldText= row.Cells[0].Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To take the value of the field from grid view, first set the datakeyname then in default.aspx.cs page write below code:

```
//this is for linkbutton onclick u can use button also
  ## Coding ## 

   protected void lnkDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         LinkButton lnkbtn = sender as LinkButton;
          GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
          string username= gvDetails.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    }
```