# GridView identify clicked row values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I have this gridview:

```
<div class="content">
    <asp:GridView ID="DocumentGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="DocumentGrid_RowCommand" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID" ItemStyle-Width="120px"/>
            <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Download Link" Text="Download"/>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

As you can see, DocumentGrid_RowCommand is called when the "Download" button is pressed, How can I find out what the values are of the row that was clicked?

Comment: I asked a similar question on here awhile back.  Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363202/in-c-how-can-i-reference-a-specific-product-record-based-on-a-button-thats-cl) will help.

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619630/getting-boundfield-value-in-gridview-row-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If more than one button fields are there in GridView, set `CommandName` attribute. That way we can determine which button is pressed in RowCommand event.  So always set commandName attribute.

```
<Columns>
 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID" ItemStyle-Width="120px"/>
 <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Download Link" Text="Download" CommandName="cmd"/>
</Columns>
```

In `RowCommand` event handler, `GridViewCommandEventArgs.CommandArgument` property returns index of row on which button is pressed.

```
 protected void DocumentGrid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "cmd")
        {
            int index = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            GridViewRow row = DocumentGrid.Rows[index];
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Response.Write(row.Cells[0].Text);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the markup like this,

```
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnDownload" CommandName="Download" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'
                        runat="server" Text="Download" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```

on the code-behind you can check the `CommandArgument` like this:

```
if (e.CommandName == "Download")
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
}
```